# API Versioning Solutions

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, docker, nginx, version-control

I'm searching for a possible solutions on how to control versioning of an API. Currently I have a non-versioned API using ASP.Net Core on a EC2 machine on AWS and I need to maintaing multiple versions of it simultaneously. I heard of a few options like:

- Different Docker containers for each version.
- A diferent proxy for each EC2 machine containing different versions.
- Controller Versioning different end-points for each version.
- AWS Api Gateway.

but I don't know much about this topics, and what is the best practices versioning and other options I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use API Gateway for this overall solution? You can use Staging to have more a version control for your API Gateway when deploying and testing. Also,
API GATEway allows you to approach API in a serverless approach and aspect.

If you want, you can use AWS Code Commit to keep track and build branches for a different version of your API.

[AWS Code Commit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/)

[API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. I'll take a lot at it. Thx

Comment: @FelipeHsu No Problem, if you find this answer of value and it helps, please upvote or mark as the answer :)